# Proof verification that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that $A_4$ has a subgroup of order $6$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of order $6$.

Since the order of $A_4$ is $12$ and the order of $H$ is $6$, we know that there are two left cosets.

Saying $A_4= H\cup gH$ for $g \in A_4$.

But, a subgroup of index $2$ in a finite group has the same number of left cosets as right cosets.

So, $gH=Hg$ for $g \in A_4$.

But, $S_4$ is not an abelian group and thus $A_4$ is not abelian group.

This implies that $gH$ is not equal to $Hg$ for $g \in A_4$ and $h \in H$.

Contradiction.

I don't know whether this is right and seems like there must be a mistake.

Anyone can check?

Comment: Your assertion that $A_{4} = H \cup gH$ for some $g \notin H$ is correct, but the fact that $gH = Hg$ does not imply that $A_{4}$ is abelian (it is a mistake in the first place to say that $gH = Hg$ means that the elements of $gH$ commute with each other). Furthermore, your suggestion that $S_{4}$ is not abelian means $A_{4}$ is not abelian is not right either, since a nonabelian group can have abelian subgroups. There are many issues here, and you may want to review some key definitions.

Comment: With respect to @Alex's comment - if $gH=Hg$, this means that $H$ is a *normal* subgroup, not that $H$ is isomorphic to an abelian group. One is a property of the abstract group, while the other is about how the group sits inside another group.

Comment: EVERY subgroup of any group as the same number of left coset as of right cosets.  The point should be, not that the NUMBER OF cosets is the same, but that the cosets themselves are the same. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The fact that a group is not abelian doesn't imply a subgroup is not abelian too. But, as other observed, $gH=Hg$ doesn't mean the group is abelian either.

Comment: As I do not wish to repeat what everyone has said, I'd suggest to think about that in a more general way. Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup if $[G:H] = 2$ it'll be good to prove that $H$ must be normal. As $V$ is the only normal subgroup of $A_4$ then it must be a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems in this proposed proof.  One is that a subgroup cannot be abelian if the whole group is not abelian.  That is wrong.  The other is that if a normal subgroup is not abelian, then the quotient group is not abelian.  That is also wrong.  See if you can find some counterexamples to both of those statements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to consider the following proof. Since index$[A_4:H]=2$, $H \unlhd A_4$. $A_4/H \cong C_2$ is abelian, so $  V_4\cong [A_4,A_4] \subseteq H$. But then $|V_4|=4 \mid |H|=6$, a contradiction.

Comment: That works much better,I think. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is here: how did you prove that bH is not Hb?? You are assuming that b*h=h*b for all h in H is equivalent to bH=Hb and that is not true. You need equality of sets so that there is no such c in G, that holds b*h = h * c. So, not that way, unless you want to use that the only normal subgroup of $A_4$ has 4 elements, and you clearly don't want.

So, a classical proof is like this: you take $A_4$. It contains: one identity(takes x to x, where x is a point, coincidence), 8 tri-cycles((1,2,3),....) , 3 double transpositions(so (1,2)(3,4),...). Now, let's suppose contrary: it is a subgroup H of order 6. H must contain identity, since it is a subgroup. From the cardinality(number of elements) it is clear that H must contain tri-cycle. Let it contain (1,2,3) without loss of generality. Then it has the inverse (1,3,2) of (1,2,3). So,three elements so far. We now need another three-cycle. Why? Why we cannot have the subgroup having three double transpositions, two permutations already given and identity?? It's not a subgroup! So, we introduce (1,2,4). We must have its inverse (1,4,2). So, five elements so far. But, we must have (1,2,3)*(1,2,4) = (1,3)(2,4) in H, because we have both (1,2,3) and (1,2,4) in H and as well (1,2,3)*(1,3)(2,4)=(2,4,3) in H, and (2,4,3) is a seventh element in H,a contradiction.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

A subgroup of index $2$ contains all squares, in particular all elements of odd order. But in $A_4$ we have eight $3$-cycles. Way too many...